# Object Required Error for attaching a file to an e-mail

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to develop an macro in excel vba to send a selected range attached to an e-mail. As my knowledge of vba is zero I have been browsing the internet and have been able to put this script together. Currently I get error of object required when i am trying to attach the file.

Appreciate every help and feedback you guys can give me.

```
Sub AttachActiveSheetPDF()
Dim IsCreated As Boolean
Dim i As Long
Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String
Dim OutlApp As Object

PdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
i = InStrRev(PdfFile, ".")
If i > 1 Then PdfFile = Left(PdfFile, i - 1)
PdfFile = PdfFile & "_" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf"

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
.Orientation = xlPortrait
.PrintArea = "$A$1:$P$84"
.Zoom = False
.FitToPagesTall = False
.FitToPagesWide = 1
End With
With ActiveSheet
.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile,       Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False,     OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err Then
Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
IsCreated = True
End If
OutlApp.Visible = True
On Error GoTo 0

Dim Ebody As String
Ebody = "<p>Buenas Dias,</p> <p>Adjunto es el documento.</p>"

With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)

.Subject = Quotation_de_Aerolinea
.To = "..."
.CC = "..."
.HTMLBody = Ebody
myAttachments.Add (PdfFile)

On Error Resume Next
.Display
Application.Visible = True
If Err Then
  MsgBox "E-mail was not sent", vbExclamation
Else
  MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", vbInformation
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `myAttachments` here ?  Do you mean `.Attachments.Add PdfFile`  ?

Comment: i thought myattachments is the command to attach a file and the filename of the pdf is in this case the pdffile

Comment: Why does PDF name contains full workbook name? You might have meant `ActiveWorkbook.Path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myAttachments` is not a collection in Outlook - looks like that may have come from some other code.

Try:

```
 .Attachments.Add PdfFile
```

Comment: this was  the mistake now its working. Thank you alot